# Jade Templating engine error

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am trying to pass some values in to a jade template through a node/express route but nothing   is getting passed on. I am posting both the server and the template code.

server.js:

app.get('/note/:id',function(request,response) {

```
    var title=notes[request.params.id]['title']

    var message=notes[request.params.id]['message']

    console.log(title+' '+message)

    response.render('note', {locals:{title:title, message:message}})
```

});

note.jade:

span #{locals.title}

I even tried to display the locals array to console but it only throws up an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you do not need to pass in the locals key. If I remember right that is only used inside the template. Give this a try.

```
response.render('note', {title:title, message:message})
```

and in your template don't use `#{locals.title}` use `#{title}`

Did a quick test and this should work for you.

Comment: What would be the template code then? Should it simply be #{title}

Comment: That's how it looks in the documentation.

Comment: Also, you should include the error in your original question, just guessing without it.